# R : Connecting to remote database on windows 8.1

Tags: r, database, remote-access

I wrote the following code to connect to a remote database:

```
ucscDb <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user="genome", host="genome-mysql.cse.ucsc.edu")
```

It shows the following error:

> Error in .local(drv, ...) :
>      Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'genome-mysql.cse.ucsc.edu' (0)

I made the setup using this link:  http://www.ahschulz.de/2013/07/23/installing-rmysql-under-windows/

Comment: maybe include your password.

Comment: @MLavoie You mean in the `dbConnect` call, right? ;)

Comment: yes, you usually need to include a password

Comment: Is the remote server (port access), mysql (`bind-address`), and the mysql user (privileges) setup for remote access?

Comment: I've edit your question. Error messages should be placed as quoted text and not as code.